# Two piped programs, one continues to run after another is killed

Tags: linux, bash, process, pipe

I have two programs piped in my bash script:

```
program1 | program2
```

The problem is that program2 can crash, and I want to make sure that when it does, program1 will end also. I tried to test this by killing program2 with

```
pkill program2
```

during execution, but the program1 continues to run.

As far as I understood, many people are asking how to make program1 continue to run because it is killed by default. Am I missing something?

Comment: `program1` won't notice that `program2` is dead until it tries to write to the pipe. Most programs will exit once they do this.

Comment: workaround: have your program1 print a progress bar or dot or something.

Comment: actually the program1 is providing constant input to program2 on certain period, and when program2 dies i get the some kind of internal error log of program1 on my console (libpng error: Write Error)

Comment: but its still trying to write every x seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an anonymous pipe, use a named pipe that gives you more control over each end.

```
mkfifo p
program1 > p &  p1_pid=$!
program2 < p
kill "$p1_pid"
```

In this snippet, we create a named pipe called `p`, then run `program1` in the background with its standard output redirected to `p`. `p1_pid` stores the process ID of `program1` for later use.  Note that `program1` is started, but immediately blocks until something opens p`for eading. We run`program2`with its standard input redirected from`p`, then block while it runs.

When `program2` exits for whatever reason, the `kill` command will send `SIGTERM` to `program1` to kill it if necessary. This has two benefits:

1. It can kill `program1` more quickly, since you don't have to wait for `program1` to write to the pipe and receive a `SIGPIPE` signal.
2. If `program1` is handling `SIGPIPE`, it may be handling other signals as well. You can use `kill` to send whatever signal is necessary (up to and including `SIGKILL`, if *really* necessary) to terminate the process.

Comment: This is a good use case for `mkfifo`. I rarely see these! It's worth noticing that `p` will be created on the file system.

Comment: is there a way to also redirect the stdout of program2 to a file? previously I had &> logfile, but I'm not sure what's the correct syntax now

Comment: Sure; `program2 < p > output 2> error`. `&> logfile` is correct for redirecting both to the same file (short for `2>&1 > logfile`).

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
program1 | program2
rc="$?"; if [ "$rc" -ne 0 ]; then killall program1 > /dev/null 2>&1; fi
```

If the above doesn't work, you may try to add

```
set -o pipefail
```

to the beginning of your script. That command would exit a pipe in which one of the steps has failed with the return code of the first failed script.

Comment: I have similar code in the rest of my bash script, but it doesn't get executed because its program1 is still alive

Comment: I added an alternative code, check if that works for you.

Comment: OK, Well, chepner's answer "kills" the problem.